# How to make function call in shared library (.so) file in php?

Tags: php, shared-libraries

I have .cpp file:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    printf("Karim");
}
```

I created .so file using this command:

```
g++ -I ./inc -fpic -c test.cpp -o LinC.o
g++ -shared -o LinC.so LinC.o
```

I want to make function call main() from php file. So how could I do t

I can use zend engine, but I dont want to use it. Any other way to do this?

Comment: If you don't like the Zend engine, use it anyway. It's good enough for what you need... (btw. every extension I know uses the Zend Engine (don't know if there are many other ways…))

Comment: It gives such impression, that you're solving your problem in wrong way. First of all, `#include stdio.h` isn't enough. You need much more. Maybe you should post the **actual** problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @DaveJust My actual program is very large. So rather confusing someone in that lenthy code, this simple program I wrote will solve the actual problem!